# Retrieve Chrome (lastpass) extension's localy stored password

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, passwords

I have forgotten my lastpass master password (my bad, the hint is not hinty enough) but chrome does know it as it logs me back to lastpass automatically on restarts and stuff...

So it must be stored on my machine by chrome.

How do i retrieve the password stored by chrome ?

I've seen a bunch of chrome password recovery but i'm not sure if that's for extension as well as websites, and they all seem pretty dodgy. i don't was to worm my computer by trying to retrieve a secure key :d

Thanks

Comment: Hmm, i'm wondering if he's not just saving a session token ... my password might not be there then.

Comment: Is your password listed under `chrome://settings/passwords`?